# servlet <error-page>によって、エラー用JSPに遷移した時にエラーコード、またはエラー名を受け取りたい

Tags: jsp, exception, servlet

現在、servletで

```html
      <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/エラーページ.jsp</location>
      </error-page>

      <error-page>
        <error-code>405</error-code>
        <location>/エラーページ.jsp</location>
      </error-page>
```

という設定をしており、ページ遷移後に何のエラーによって遷移してきたかを判断したいと考えております。
そのために、エラーコードまたはエラー名をエラーページ.jspで取得したいのですが、方法が分かりません。
解決方法の分かる方がいましたらご教授をお願いします。

また、<%= exception %>やリクエストの中身には、目的のデータは格納されていないようでした。servletの設定方法で、パラメータを渡す設定が出来ないか調査しています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

error-pageで制御せず、servletでfilterを設定します。
filterで指定したクラス内の処理で、リクエストにエラー文言を入れます。

error-pageを使用していないので、エラー種別はjava側で判定し割り出すしかないです。
例えあ、アクセスURL内に特定の文言が含まれていない場合は不正アクセスとする　など・・

Answer (score 1):

エラー用のJSPファイルのヘッダにて、

```
<%@ page isErrorPage="true" %>
```

とすることで、JSP内で 暗黙オブジェクトである exception が扱えるようになります。
exceptionオブジェクトには、サーブレットやJSPで発生した例外が入っていますので、例外クラスによって表示を切り替えるのも可能でしょう。

ただし、exceptionで拾うのはサーブレットやJSPなどJava内で発生した例外を扱うものです。
具体的な例を挙げると、HTTPレスポンスコード404のようにリソースが存在しないURLを指定した場合にはサーブレットが実行されませんので適しません。

以下の記事も参考にしてください。

2.5. exception - Techscore様
http://www.techscore.com/tech/Java/JavaEE/JSP/2-5/